# How do I bind a button combo to an action in Steam input?

Tags: steam, steam-input

I want to configure a control scheme in Steam Input where a combination of 2 buttons triggers an action. More specifically, I want to make it so holding the d-pad left or right then pressing R2 will double tap the d-pad.

How do I bind a button combination to an action with Steam Input?